# Wrong position in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

There is an img with a text over a banner at http://npl.ibles.pl. It is positioned too low in IE8 by a half of its height. Could you help me to find out why please?

Comment: can u post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an IE 8 conditional comment in the `head` and give to the `#site-slogan` approx `bottom: 16px;`
Exapmle:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>    
  <style>
    #site-slogan {
        bottom: 16px;
    }       
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I have thought about it, but hoped to find a better solution. Thanks.